# map function not returning the data to the render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
userid(uid){
    this.state.userid.map((user)=>{
      if(uid===user._id){
        console.log(user.username)
        return user.username
      }
    })
  }
```

---

```
<div style={{width:"80%"}}>

{this.state.posts.map(post=>
  <div key={post._id.toString()}>
    <div className="modal-content"><br/>
    <a >{this.**userid**(post.user_id)}</a>        
    <b>Title: {post.title}</b><br/>
    <div><b>Message: </b>{post.message}</div>
```

---

I'm calling the user id from the return render, but it is not returning back, is there any way to return

Comment: Problem appears in `if(uid===user._id){` you are not passing uid to your callback function, only passing `user` object. Hence it never pass the result.

Comment: yea, but how could i modify now to get the exact return